# Is it a good idea to use fb.me over facebook.com in advertising material?

Tags: social-media, urls, marketing, advertisement

Apologies if there's a better Stack site for this, but I can't think of what it could be.

I'm designing some flyers for an upcoming side business of mine, and need to include a link to my Facebook page on these flyers.

As far as I can tell there are just two ways that I can do this:

- *facebook.com/MyBusinessName*
- *fb.me/MyBusinessName*

For the purposes of brevity and ease-of-typing, I want to go for the latter, but I'm wondering whether there might be any implications of doing so, user experience or otherwise.

For example, are users likely to be more suspicious of typing in the unfamiliar *fb.me* link as opposed to a *facebook.com* one?

The target audience includes enterprise users, so how likely is it that the relatively unknown *fb.me* will be blocked behind corporate firewalls whereas the standard Facebook one won't?

As a very related question, is it necessary to include a link at all? Would the Facebook page's name alongside a Facebook icon suffice for the average user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, a couple of points:

> For example, are users likely to be more suspicious of typing in the unfamiliar fb.me link as opposed to a facebook.com one?

This is definitely possible, I'm fairly tech-savvy (software developer by trade) and I'm not 100% sure that fb.me is legit. You should ideally test this with your users, are they put off? do they know fb.me is a legit site? You could commission a remote survey to test this kind of thing. Personally I'd suggest there is a risk with any shortened link of mistrust.

> The target audience includes enterprise users, so how likely is it that the relatively unknown fb.me will be blocked behind corporate firewalls whereas the standard Facebook one won't?

Whilst this is possible, the opposite is also possible. I know of companies that block social networks explicitly.

> As a very related question, is it necessary to include a link at all? Would the Facebook page's name alongside a Facebook icon suffice for the average user?

Good question, this would depend on what you expect to happen with your flyers, is the user sitting at a computer typing content from the flyer into their address bar? or have they remembered the name and are doing it without?

As a final UX point, there is no such thing as an "average user". The best thing you can do is try to understand who your specific users are and ask them, perhaps through surveys, interviews etc, or observe them, perhaps through interviews, testing or existing metrics. Find out what works for that specific demographic etc and go with that.